# Does $252$ have an inverse modulo $198$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

On a discrete math test this semester, a question asked if $n$ has an inverse modulo $m$, where $n = 252$ and $m = 198$.

I argued that the inverse modulo did not exist because there is no divisor that would leave a remainder $198$ for $252$. This solution was accepted, but I was marked down a point because my answer was not thorough enough. Could someone please explain in greater detail how this is not possible?

Comment: *"There is no divisor that would leave a remainder of 198 for 252":* it's not clear to me what you mean by this.  Certainly, there exist values of $n$ such that $n/252$ leaves a remainder of 198.  For example, $n = 198$ or $n = 198 + 252$.

Comment: It's not clear what your proposed proof means. Could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If so then $\ 252\,x\equiv 1\pmod{\!198}\,\Rightarrow\,252x+198n = 1\,\Rightarrow\,1\,$ is even, contradiction.

**Remark** $\ $ The same method shows that invertible integers must be coprime to the modulus $\,m.\,$ This necessary condition is also sufficient since, by Bezout, $\,\gcd(a,m) = 1\,$ $\Rightarrow\,$ $ja+km =1,\,$ for integers $\,j,k,\,$ hence $\, ja\equiv 1\pmod{m}.\,$ The extended Euclidean algorithm will compute $j$ (and the Bezout identity)

Answer (score 1):

$252$ and $198$ are not coprime: they are both divisible by $2$, so any multiple of $252$ will be divisible by $2$ modulo $198$.

Answer (score 0):

They are both even numbers. Therefore one can't have an inverse modulo the other, for instance by the Chinese remainder theorem or the euclidean algorithm plus the fact that $\gcd$ is the smallest possible positive linear combination of two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In general we have that $a$ has inverse $\bmod m$ if and only if $a$ and $m$ are coprime.

Clearly $252$ and $198$ are not coprime.